# MethodBuilder ILGenerator get class property

Tags: c#

I'm trying to acces the property of the class my Methodbuilder method is being defined in.
This is my current code:

```
Type[] types = { typeof(HttpListenerContext) };
TypeBuilder tb = GetTypeBuilder(type.Name);
ConstructorBuilder constructor = tb.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);
MethodBuilder mB = tb.DefineMethod("Init", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual, null, types);
ILGenerator il = mB.GetILGenerator();

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, typeof(Page).GetProperty("_POST").GetValue(??));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(DataSet).GetMethod("SetData"));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

tb.DefineMethodOverride(mB, typeof(Page).GetMethod("Init"));

try
{
    Type tc = tb.CreateType();
    Page test = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(tc);
    test.Init();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

This is is class I'm trying to get the property from:

```
public class Page
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> _POST { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> _GET { get; set; }
    public Head Headers { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode = 200;

    public virtual void Init(HttpListenerContext ctx = null) { }

    public virtual void Load() { }

    public virtual string Send() { return ""; }
    public virtual string Send(string response) { return ""; }
}
```

The current typebuilder has Page as parent, how can I get a nonstatic value set in my typebuilder class? Like how could I get my method to Console.WriteLine the value of _POST?

```
private TypeBuilder GetTypeBuilder(string name)
{
     string typeSignature = name;
     AssemblyName aN = new AssemblyName(typeSignature);
     AssemblyBuilder aB = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(aN, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
     ModuleBuilder mB = aB.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
     TypeBuilder tB = mB.DefineType(typeSignature + "h",
     TypeAttributes.Public |
     TypeAttributes.Class |
     TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
     TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
     TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
     TypeAttributes.AutoLayout,
     typeof(Page));

     return tB;
}


    ILGenerator il = mB.GetILGenerator();

    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, typeof(Page).GetProperty("ContentType").GetGetMethod());
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) }));
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    tb.DefineMethodOverride(mB, typeof(Page).GetMethod("Init"));
```

I'm setting the value of ContentType before I'm getting it with my function.

Comment: The easiest way to solve this type of problems is to write the code you are trying to generate in C# and then ildasm it.

Comment: @zespri So should I write a short line like `Console.WriteLine(this._POST);` and then ildasm it?

Comment: Well, yes, just don't forget to put it into a method/class that you are trying to generate. But see Luaan's answer below for possible ready solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're creating an instance method on a type that inherits from `Page`. If that's the case, this is the code you want:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);  // Load the this reference
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Page).GetProperty("_POST").GetGetMethod());
```

Also, note that [`DataSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't have a `SetData` method - if that's an extension method, you need to use the real type where it's defined rather than `DataSet`.

Comment: By executing these lines: `il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Page).GetProperty("_POST").GetGetMethod());` I'm getting the error Jit compiler encountered an internal limitation. What is causing this?

Comment: @StijnBernards in your question you are trying to `ldstr` a `Dictionary`. That obviously would not work. Is this your problem?

Comment: I think not as for now I'm calling the get function of the _POST variable and that is returning an error, I've added the typebuilder function maybe I've messed up the class extending?

Comment: @StijnBernards Well, `ILGenerator` has no sanity checking - you have to make sure *everything* is proper. What are you doing with the values remaining on the stack? Are you doing all the required casts etc.? Is your stack empty by the time you get to `ret`? Also, are you sure `typeof(Page).GetProperty("_POST")` doesn't return null?

Comment: @StijnBernards You're using `Ldstr` again - that's just for loading literal strings. You want to use `Call` instead.